# Prevent background from showing with jquery cycle plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

Fairly simple, if you use the cycle plugin for jquery and create a slideshow the transition between slides allows what's beneath the slides to show. I want to avoid this and have one slide truly fade into the other rather than kind of fading into the background and then into the next slide.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Example:
http://www.sonicinteractive.com.au/_WIP/slider_problem/

See how the white line (and background) come through..

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: I dont know if your plug in support this, have you looked at this page [Documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)? maybe you can find some options in there that can help you

Comment: what happens if you use shuffle or zoom? Do you still see the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place an image below them but above the page with a neutral colour that blocks out the page background in the region of the image (i.e. create it from the same mask used for the images themselves).

Comment: Yeah, that's the only thing I could think of too

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have solved the problem by removing the background colour of the wrappers containing the slider as well as the "main wrapper". For the latter I only left the backgound-image to do the job.

Hope that this helps